# Help with regular expression

Tags: regex, perl

In the following expression:

```perl
if (($$_ =~ /^.+:\s*\#\s*abcd\s+XYZ/)
```

1. Where is $$_ taken from?
2. The right side of the expression means to match one or more characters plus followed by colon, followed by zero or more spaces followed by # followed by one or more spaces folowed by 'abcd' followed by zero or more spaces followed by 'XYZ'?

Comment: Just to clarify, `\s` is not only a space its a whitespace character, that means it can also be a tab or a line break character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the last "one or more" and "zero or more" reversed from what the regex actually does.

`$$_` dereferences the scalar reference in `$_`.

Comment: Sorry, please clarify about $$_. If $_ is currently 'def', what does $$_ do?

Comment: @jasonline: It's a reference. Like this: `my $x = "foo"; $y = \$x; $$y =~ s/f/b/; print $x; ` -- action on reference affects original variable. See [perldoc perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) for more.

Comment: @jasonline, If `$_` is `def` and you are using `use strict;` as you should, `$$_` throws an error since `def` is not a reference.

Comment: And if you aren't using strict, `$$_` gets the value of `$def`.

Answer (score 1):

Concerning 2., your explanation of the regex is not entirely correct.

```
/^.+:\s*#\s*abcd\s+XYZ/
```

means one or more characters (starting at the beginning of the string) followed by a colon, followed by zero or more whitespace characters, followed by one hash character, followed by zero or more whitespace characters, followed by 'abcd', followed by one or more whitespace characters, followed by 'XYZ'.

Answer (score 1):

**As for pt. 2:**

Line beginning with (`^`) one or more characters (`.+`), colon (`:`), zero or more whitespace characters (`\s*`), a hash (`\#`), *zero or more* whitespace characters (`\s*`), the string "abcd" (`abcd`), *one or more* whitespace characters (`\s+`), then the string "XYZ" (`XYZ`).

(emphasis added on discrepancies.) Do note that there is no anchor on the end of line (`$`), thus this only concerns the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this site](http://chris.photobooks.com/regex/default.htm)

Here is the given explanation of your regex:

```
Token    Meaning

^        Matches beginning of input. If the multiline flag is set to true, 
         also matches immediately after a line break character.
.+       Matches any single character except newline characters.
         The + quantifier causes this item to be matched 1 or more times (greedy).
:        :
\s*      Matches a single white space character.
         The * quantifier causes this item to be matched 0 or more times (greedy).
\#       #
\s*      Matches a single white space character.
         The * quantifier causes this item to be matched 0 or more times (greedy).
abcd     abcd
\s+      Matches a single white space character.
         The + quantifier causes this item to be matched 1 or more times (greedy).
XYZ      XYZ
```